# 100% height of parent block minus content above?

Tags: html, css

I have something like this:

```
<div class="block">
    <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias illo, magni dolores animi at rem laboriosam quisquam vitae voluptatibus possimus officia dolore nobis. Aspernatur, perspiciatis nobis ipsum et ullam adipisci.
    </div>
    <div class="textarea"><textarea name="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.block {
    background: #eee;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}

.textarea {
    height: 100%;
}

.textarea textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

How it looks you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/u6kdp3yk/

Is it possible without JS only using CSS make `.textarea` section 100% height of parent block but without height of `.text` section? And `.text` section height is dynamic and depend on content length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on [compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) requirements you could always use the flex box model, like so:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.block {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
textarea {
  width: 100%;
  
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <p class="text">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias illo, magni dolores animi at rem laboriosam quisquam vitae voluptatibus possimus officia dolore nobis. Aspernatur, perspiciatis nobis ipsum et ullam adipisci.
  </p>
  <textarea name="" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</div>
```

I also changed the HTML mark-up slightly - the changes are purely for better semantics: you can change it back if you want.